# Sort legend order in ggmap

Tags: r, legend, ggmap

How can I sort the legend order in a ggmap? I have the following code:

```
mymap <- ggmap(map) + geom_point(data = mypoints, aes(x =lon, y= lat,colour = month), alpha=0.5, size=5)
```

I would like the months to appear in order (i.e. Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr... etc.)

Comment: Have a look at: http://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2012/10/15/how-do-i-re-arrange-ordering-a-plot/ This is not about ggplot but factor levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

As stated by Tyler Rinker, one way is to use the function `factor` to order factor levels (in this case, *months*).
I created some data to use with ggplot, but you can adapt to your data and use the logic with ggmap.

```
library(ggplot)

x = c(6.2, 2.3, 0, 1.54, 2.17, 6.11, 0.3,
  1.39, 5.14, 12.52, 12.57, 7.13, 13.71)

y = c(7.89, 7.63, 5.29, 8.38, 8.37, 10.5, 21.5,
  16.65, 23.76, 1.77, 1.8, 10.49, 14.01)

month = month.abb  # system constant in correct sort order.

mypoints = data.frame(cbind(x,y,month))

mypoints$month = factor(mypoints$month, 
                       levels=month.abb ) 

ggplot(data = mypoints,aes(x,y)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=month), alpha=0.5, size=5)
```

[image]